# Simplifying an expression with a nested radical

Tags: radicals

I'm doing some work on functions and have come across a problem in which I need to simplify a certain expression. I can't move any further on because I'm unsure of how to simplify this expression!

Here it is:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x^2-1}}}
$$

Any help is appreciated, thanks so much!

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{x^2 - 1}}}$?

Comment: Wasn't this question asked 30 minutes ago?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes! Thank you

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig That's great, thanks!

Comment: On that post, I wrote a comment exactly like N.F Taussig. Deja vu!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is much that can be done. If you want to avoid the "square root inside square root", you can expand the fraction with $\sqrt{1-\sqrt{x^2-1}}$ or $\sqrt{\sqrt{x^2-1} - 1}$, depending on which version produces a positive discriminant:

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x^2-1}}} = \frac{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{x^2-1}}}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}
$$